# add one more to qty of product in cart programtically

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

If an item from category id = 525 is added to the cart, this code should add one more to quantity if quantity is 1, then a promo on the admin panel is set which will give customer 50 % discount but this code is not adding one more to cart and not giving any errors. How do I make this work?

```
public function salesruleValidatorProcess(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /* @var $quote Mage_Sales_Model_Quote */
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
    /* @var $rule Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule */
    $rule = $observer->getEvent()->getRule();
    $category = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');

    if ($rule->getSimpleAction() != C4B_Freeproduct_Model_Consts::ADD_GIFT_ACTION
        || $item->getIsFreeProduct()
        || $rule->getIsApplied())
    {
        return;
    }

    ////
    $qty="2";
$cid="525";
$Qty1 = $item->getQty();
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
if ($cid==$item->getCategoryId() && ($Qty1=1)){
$item->setQty($qty);
}
}

}
```

Comment: please clear your requirement with example

Comment: if an item from category 525 is added to the cart and the quantity is 1 then it should add 1 more in the cart and give discount 50% off

Comment: means final quantity will be 2 and 50% off overall or for just that category product?

Comment: 50% off overall **OR** for just that category product?

Comment: just the category product

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    if ($cid==$item->getCategoryId() && ($Qty1=1)){
        $item->setQty($qty);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($item->getPrice()/2);
        $item->save();  
    }
}
```